# Innodb_buffer_pool_size not set

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to update MySQL "innodb_buffer_pool_size" in windows server. I have run "set global innodb_buffer_pool_size=256*1024*1024".
After I restart the server it's set back to 8M again.

If I change my.ini file then MySQL57 service is not running.

I am using MySQL 5.7.36.

Comment: No, there is no log. The buffer size is reset to default value

Answer (score 0):

To save setting, you need to put them in a my.ini file that the mysql server reads on startup.

`SET GLOBAL...` only affect the current running instance.

Comment: I tried with changing value in my.ini file. It's not working, I meant mysql service is not run after changed the my.ini file.